# Creating a single SmartTV app for multiple platforms?

Tags: google-tv, samsung-smart-tv, design-guidelines

I want to develop a SmartTV application for the GoogleTV platform and i've been browsing trough the GoogleTV Guidelines (https://developers.google.com/tv/android/).

However, i don't want GoogleTV to be my only platform. I also want the same app to work on devices like Samsung SmartTV and/or LG SmartTV. 
But do the guidelines from Google conflict with Samsung guidelines and does the code of my application need a lot of rework to work on other devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm editing my answer.  I just checked the Samsung website and, I'm happy to say, they threw out all the junk.

They use to have a number of different, non-interchangeable, coding languages. And none of them really worked on the TV's of the other manufacturers either.   This is most likely the reason why few applications were ever developed for those platforms.

Now they are supporting basic javascript.  So, you have the opportunity to build yourself a TV web page and load it up as an application on Samsung and potentially run it from the Google-TV browser.   However, I would verify whether your application requires specific HTML5 features (such as offline support) that may not be implemented in the Android-like browser version running on Google-TV.   Having said that, you can always build an app that loads locally on Samsung and runs from a remote server on Google-TV?

... for some historical perspective on how we go to where we're at you can continue reading....

The implication of each manufacturer having their own unique OS creating developer fragmentation was probably predictable to them but they were likely working in a panic.  After they became aware of the Apple TV when the first patents were make public in 2008 they understood the longer term impact if Apple provided hundred of thousand of applications worth of content and they had nothing to compete.   So they got together and decided on a standard they would implement that would provide a non-fragmented solution allowing any app to run on the TV's of any supporting manufacturer.   AKA: they got it right.

In 2009 a good number of them announced support for the Yahoo Connected TV standard.   However, by 2010 the development framework, app store, etc that was promised had not materialized.   This is likely when they all went in their own direction (although you can still buy Yahoo Connected TV sets from Samsung, Sony, LG, Vizio, and Panasonic today).

With the implementation of the Google-TV Market and the ability of developers to transition existing apps to Google-TV apps with only 20% or so of the effort of creating new (thus lowering the cost and supporting the business case for a TV version) that they have a solution that meets their original requirements.

Now, there's certainly going to be a little 'bitten once twice shy' coupled with revenue sharing discussions and perhaps the impact of Google being a hardware manufacturer (Motorola Mobility) but, at the end of the day, the inevitable is inevitable.  They either take Google-TV or create their own, very close, must run existing applications, version of Android.

PS: I didn't look at the other manufacturers site.

Answer (score 2):

For my understanding core components like the Player and Remote Control Management are platform specific.

You would need to use a configuration file and implements these components independently for each platform.

Alternatively you can use some cross platform SDK.

Searching on Google for "smart tv app development" I found out:

Joshfire Smart TV SDK

http://www.joshfire.com/products/

- Works on Google TV and Samsung
- But not on LG

Mautilus Smart TV SDK

http://www.mautilus.com/knowhow/smart-tv-application-development/
As written in their website it covers

- LG Netcast 2012
- Samsung 2012 / 2013 models.

I hope it can helps.

Answer (score 1):

[orangeejs](https://github.com/orangeejs/orangeejs) is a new open source project aims to ease the pain of cross platform smart tv app development. The target platforms are latest model of samsung/lg/android/ios.

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework developed by BBC and called [TAL](http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/index.html). It aims to help you with cross-platform development. All their Smart TV apps were developed using this library so take a look.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you consider to develop for many TV platforms see the: 
https://developers.google.com/tv/web/lib/jquery/

It's jQuery library for Google TV, so you can develop application in HTML/JavaScript just like in Samsung and LG.

Of course there are the differences in key handling, video player, event handling so you will need to develop the framework which cover all this differences.

There are few open source frameworks out there but not mature enough to use it "out of the box".
for example: http://framework.joshfire.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [cloudee-couch](https://github.com/Boxee/cloudee-couch) which is open-sourced by Boxee. This example/framework is built on top of Spine.js. Base classes take care of key handling, focus, and oauth authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal to make an application for the smart tv platform that supports across the devices. Now the industry is filled with a lot of smart tv app development companies with their unique functionalities and features to offer the customized app as per the business models. FYI I'd suggest you choose the best smart tv app builder from the list. Hope it will be helpful for the video content creators & business owners to stream across the tv.

1. VPlayed
2. Zype
3. Uscreen

Explore the complete list here Ref: https://dev.to/dwarak17/5-smart-tv-app-development-companies-to-develop-tv-apps-in-2021-1584

Answer (score -2):

While both Samsung and LG have proprietary Smart TV systems, they also both support Google TV.  If you create an app for Google TV, you'll only have to write it once and it will run on Samsung's Google TV's, LG's Google TV's, Vizio's Google TV's, and Sony's Google TV's.

Comment: I did read that Samsung and LG were stepping into the GoogleTV boat, but I actually meant their own systems. LG and Samsung provide their own SDK's for app-development and they seem to have some different rules applied.