# Samsung TV application development using android

Tags: android, google-tv, samsung-smart-tv

There shows an application development kit exists for Samsung smart TV. But my doubt is that will it support android applications. Does all the smart TV's are Google powered? will they all support android application.

Answer (score 2):

Samsung's 2012 TV range will be running the Google TV software in some fashion (I'm not sure what fashion, but I believe it will sit alongside or on top of Samsung's existing system).

Google TV is Android powered.

You won't be able to take advantage of it if you want to support TVs released in 2011 or earlier.

Comment: Do you mean, its better to use samsung sdk to create application for samsung smart tv?

Comment: "Better" is subjective and depends on lots of different factors. You aren't going to get an Android application to run on a Samsung 2011 TV though.

Answer (score 1):

On normal 2012 Samsung models you won't run Android app too.

Samsung and Google has signed agreement, but it will be only for one or two TV sets models as it is with Sony and LG.

So if you want to make applications for Samsung - forget about android apps, use HTML/JavaScript.

And I mentioned it already here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881869/364483 - you can also make HTML/Javascript Apps for Google TV.